# Average of two columns sum in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns, for example:
A(10,15,30) and B(2,3,No data)

And I need average: sum(a)/sum(B) but without sum any cell in A column if cell in the same row of B column is empty. I need a formula for this...
Based on this example, I'm looking for a formula which will give me average 5((10+15)/(2+3)), not 11((10+15+30)/(2+3)).

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
=SUMIF(B:B,"<>",A:A)/SUM(B:B)
```

[image]